# Have multiple intervals in a staggered animation

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to have a tween that can have multiple intervals in a staggered in serval e.g.

> opacity goes from 1.0 to 0.0 (% time: 0.45 to 0.5)

then

> opacity goes from 0.0 to 1.0 (% time: 0.5 to 0.55)

using a similar tween

```
opacity1 = Tween<double>(
      begin: 1.0,
      end: 0.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Interval(
          0.45, 0.5,
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
      ),
    ).NextTween<double>( ///Pseudo code
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Interval(
          0.5, 0.55,
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: check `TweenSequence`, but you can also create your custom `Curve` by implementing `Curve.transform` method

Answer (score 2):

Ok in the end I use a TweenSquence the flutter docs uses the example below which is very helpful link to the docs is [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html).

> This example defines an animation that uses an easing curve to interpolate between 5.0 and 10.0 during the first 40% of the animation, remains at 10.0 for the next 20%, and then returns to 5.0 for the final 40%.

```
final Animation<double> animation = TweenSequence(


 <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 5.0, end: 10.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
      weight: 40.0,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(10.0),
      weight: 20.0,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 10.0, end: 5.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
      weight: 40.0,
    ),
  ],
).animate(myAnimationController);
```